# How to delete in a batch using Oracle SQL stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to delete in a batch of 90 days record from a table using an Oracle stored procedure.

First I want to fetch a year worth record from `tbl1` and from that cursor, I want to fetch 90 days record, then keep deleting in bulk of 90 days range from `tbl1` and `tbl2`, and commit each batch separately, so I will have a max 0f 4 or 5 commit for a year range records.

However the following stored procedure is deleting in a row by row instead of a bulk. I want to know how can I achieve the intended result using an Oracle stored procedure? Thanks

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr2 
AS
    TYPE bulk_type IS TABLE OF tbl1.nameid%type;
  v_batch bulk_type;
  v_size number;
  v_time TIMESTAMP := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  v_max_time INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := INTERVAL '0 00:05:00' DAY TO SECOND;


  CURSOR deleter IS
    SELECT nameid
    FROM tbl1
    WHERE regDate >= '01-Jan-22' AND regDate <= '01-Dec-22'
    ORDER BY regDate;

BEGIN
  OPEN deleter;
  FETCH deleter BULK COLLECT INTO v_batch;

  WHILE deleter%FOUND LOOP
    
    for delete_buk in (select nameid from tbl1 where regDate <= (select min(regDate) + interval '90' day from tbl1)
    and nameid in (v_batch.nameid));

    LOOP
        BEGIN

    DELETE FROM tbl2
    WHERE nameid = delete_buk.nameid; 

    DELETE FROM tbl2
    WHERE id = delete_buk.nameid;
    
    v_size:= sql%rowcount;
    COMMIT;


    INSERT INTO log(log_t) VALUES (v_size || ' id deleted');


    IF CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - start_time >= max_time THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE deleter;

END pr2;
```

Comment: You open a cursor and then you use `WHILE` loop to start reading the cursor and then a `FOR` loop to loop through all the values in the same table and delete rows starting from the minimum, ignoring the cursor and the bounds set in the cursor, so you are going to delete **EVERYTHING** in the table that matches `tbl2` with `tbl1`. I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do but deleting using loops within loops is not the way to do it.

Comment: the for loop is used to fetch a 90 day range records from the cursor , and keep deleting in a 90 day range batch , but the delete statement is not deleting in a bulk, instead it is deleting row by row .

Comment: No, it isn't. The loop fetches 90 days from the minimum value in the table, not 90 days from the minimum value in the cursor. You do not even reference the cursor in the `FOR` loop's `SELECT` statement.

Comment: in this case the minimum regDate is '01-Jan-22' and I referred the cursor in the where loop, but didn't work as I wanted it to work :(

Answer (score 4):

Don't use loops, just delete the rows in one go:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE pr2 
AS
  v_size PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM tbl2
  WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT 1
          FROM   tbl1
          WHERE  regDate >= DATE '2022-01-01'
          AND    regDate < DATE '2023-01-01'
          AND    (  tbl1.nameid = tbl2.nameid
                 OR tbl1.id     = tbl2.id )
        ); 

  v_size:= sql%rowcount;
  INSERT INTO log(log_t) VALUES (v_size || ' id deleted');
END pr2;
/
```

If you really want to delete it in 4 sets (don't, it'll be less efficient) then delete it in 3-month blocks (as there are 365 or 366 days in a year, not 4-lots-of-90 which would be 360):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_tbl2_range(
  i_start_date IN DATE,
  i_end_date IN DATE
)
AS
  v_size PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM tbl2
  WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT 1
          FROM   tbl1
          WHERE  regDate >= i_start_date
          AND    regDate < i_end_date
          AND    (  tbl1.nameid = tbl2.nameid
                 OR tbl1.id     = tbl2.id )
        ); 

  v_size:= sql%rowcount;
  INSERT INTO log(log_t) VALUES (v_size || ' id deleted');
END delete_tbl2_range;
/

CREATE PROCEDURE pr2 
AS
BEGIN
  DELETE_TBL2_RANGE(DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-04-01');
  DELETE_TBL2_RANGE(DATE '2022-04-01', DATE '2022-07-01');
  DELETE_TBL2_RANGE(DATE '2022-07-01', DATE '2022-10-01');
  DELETE_TBL2_RANGE(DATE '2022-10-01', DATE '2023-01-01');
END pr2;
/
```

*Note: you should not `COMMIT` in a procedure as it prevents you from chaining multiple procedures together and, if a latter one fails, using `ROLLBACK` to roll them all back. Instead, `COMMIT` from the code where you call the procedure(s).*

---

If you want to pass the start date into the procedure and delete in 90 day ranges then:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_tbl2_year(
  i_start_date IN DATE
)
AS
BEGIN
  DELETE_TBL2_RANGE(
    i_start_date,
    i_start_date + INTERVAL '90' DAY
  );
  DELETE_TBL2_RANGE(
    i_start_date + INTERVAL '90' DAY,
    i_start_date + INTERVAL '180' DAY
  );
  DELETE_TBL2_RANGE(
    i_start_date + INTERVAL '180' DAY,
    i_start_date + INTERVAL '270' DAY
  );
  DELETE_TBL2_RANGE(
    i_start_date + INTERVAL '270' DAY,
    i_start_date + INTERVAL '360' DAY
  );
  DELETE_TBL2_RANGE(
    i_start_date + INTERVAL '360' DAY,
    ADD_MONTHS(i_start_date, 12)
  );
END delete_tbl2_year;
/
```

Comment: I can't go delete all the records in one go, the reason I'm using the loop is I want to keep deleting in a batch until the fetched data from the cursor is empty.

Comment: @thecoder We don't understand why because you are not explaining the logic of why loops are necessary (and your code is a tangled mess which almost certainly does not do what you think it does). You should [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77559705/edit) and explain everything properly.

Comment: yes, the sp is not doing what I think it does , instead It is deleting row by row all of the fetched records. What I want is fetch a year worth record from tb1, then delete in a 90 days range as a batch and keep deleting until the 1 year record is deleted. so I there will be a max 4 or 5 commit for the year range record

Comment: @thecoder Then use the second half of my answer and use 90-day ranges and not 3-month ranges. (But its still not advisable to `COMMIT` in a procedure). You still do not need to use loops.

Comment: ok, the regDate will be not hardcoded tho. any thought on how can I keep deleting in a 90 days range until the fetched 1 year record is empty ? and I don't need to rollback all commits if 1 failed, just the failed one will be rolled back, that is why I wanted to commit each batch separately

Comment: @thecoder Yes, its easy. Just pass the start date in as an argument and then call the other procedure with 90 day ranges. If you must `COMMIT` then add it into the `delete_tbl2_range` procedure (but you know my views on that).

Comment: ok, Thanks! will try that